# What is the hook to obtain the path and the name of the file that is being uploaded?

Tags: uploads

I work in a plugin in which I need to obtain information of the current file that is uploaded. To this end, in the plugin I use a filter as follows.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'custom_handle_upload', 10, 1);

function custom_handle_upload($upload) {
    $file = $upload['file'];
    $type = $upload['type'];

    if (hasValidType($type) && hasValidName($file)) {
        parseXLSX($file);
    }
}
```

If the file has the valid type and the name is correct, then it is processed. Otherwise the import should follow the normal flow.

But it is not the case, the file is uploaded to the upload directory but no data about the file is added to the database.

So I end up with broken references to the file.

When debugging the process and get to the function `media_handle_upload` located in `wp-admin/includes/media.php` I discover that the value of `$file` is `null`

```
$file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES[$file_id], $overrides, $time);
```

If I deactivate the plugin, the import works as expected.

In order to solve, first try to change filter to action but the same thing happens. At this moment I think I should use another hook. I do not know what it could be and I do not know if it is correct.

What is the hook to obtain the path and the name of the file that is being uploaded?

I appreciate your opinion

**Update:** Actual solution

When uploading, the function `media_handle_upload` located at `wp-admin/includes/media.php` is invoked and at some point it call `wp_handle_upload` method. [This method on success, returns an associative array of file attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload), so from the custom method I return the uploaded file. At the moment it looks like this

```
function custom_handle_upload($upload) {
    $file = $upload['file'];
    $type = $upload['type'];

    if (hasValidType($type) && hasValidName($file)) {
        parseXLSX($file);
    }

    return $upload;
}
```

And this allow me to upload common, and target files with it data

Comment: Is this an upload you triggered? Or is this trying to hook into arbitrary media library uploads? Have you confirmed that the problem isn't with your if statement check?

Comment: I am using media library uploads to upload the file, I can confirm the problem is not in the if statement. I am new to WordPress and because I do not know the terms I mention that the file I upload using the options in the media library in the site administration

Comment: I got to fix the problem. I will update the question

Comment: Can you post the answer as an answer?